# connect to sharePoint site behind a proxy using RestApi

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api, reverse-proxy, proxy

Trying to connect to SiteCollection with RestAPI , but i got the error of , proxy not authorised .

> "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication
>   Required."

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

most probably related to your proxy settings on machine from which you connect.

Have a look a this article on how to resolve it. 
https://www.sharepointsky.com/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-407-proxy-authentication-required/

Comment: actually i need to pass by a proxy  the acces is remoted,, passing proxy credential is need ,without any config for the navigator